# Confused why this doesn't produce a straight line of slope 1 and angle 45

Tags: python, numpy, math

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Python program for slope of line
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (float)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

midPoint = 400
tenPercentOfMidpoint = .10 * midPoint

x = np.linspace(midPoint - tenPercentOfMidpoint, midPoint + tenPercentOfMidpoint, 50)
m = np.empty(x.shape)
c = np.empty(x.shape)

m[(x>=midPoint)] = 1.0
m[(x<midPoint)] = 1.0
c[x<midPoint] = 0
c[x>=midPoint] = 0

y=m*x+c

lenOfx = len(x)
lenOfy = len(y)
s = slope(0, y[0], lenOfx, y[lenOfy - 1])
angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(x[-1] - x[0], lenOfy - 0))
```

If I now print `s`

```
print(s)
```

the result is 1.6

If I print the `angle`

```
print(angle)
```

the result is 57.99

**I want a line between `midPoint - tenPercent and midPoint + tenPercent` that has `slope` 1 and `angle` 45**

Comment: Your creation of `m` and `c` is unnecessarily complicated.  In any case `y=1*x+0` means `y` has the same values as `x`.  Both are 50 points between 360 and 440.  I don't know what your 'slope' calculation is supposed to do, at least not with those arguments.  The function looks ok, but the arguments don't make any sense.

Comment: If that is true, then why doesn't slope give 1 and angle 45?

Comment: Also, why substract zero in the final line?  (`lenOfy - 0`)

Comment: Just for clarity sake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just a problem of plugging in things incorrectly.  The points you are testing in your `slope` are `(0, y[0])` == `(0, 360.0)` and `(lenOfx, y[lenOfy - 1])` == `(50, 440.0)`; **these points are not on the line defined by `y=m*x+c`**.  I believe you instead want to pull the two endpoints of the segment:

```
>>> slope(x[0], y[0], x[-1], y[-1]) # (360.0, 360.0, 440.0, 440.0)
1.0
```

Similar problem for calculating the angle; you want to use the change in `y` and the change in `x`:

```
>>> np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y[-1] - y[0], x[-1] - x[0]))
45.0
```

The number of coordinates (`len`) should not be relevant to the slope calculation.

Note that `x` and `y` are the same (`x == y` returns a vector of `True`).

Comment: Oops I guess I am tired.

Answer (score 0):

For a line to have a slope of 1, the change in y should be same as change in x i.e. by definition of slope

> I want a line between midPoint - tenPercent and midPoint + tenPercent that has slope 1 and angle 45

The closest thing to a line of slope 1 would be by changing x

```
x = np.linspace(midPoint - tenPercentOfMidpoint, midPoint + tenPercentOfMidpoint, int(2*tenPercentOfMidpoint))
```

or by changing tenPercentOfMidpoint to a number such that

```
2*tenPercentOfMidpoint=50  ## because you mentioned 50 in np.linspace
tenPercentOfMidpoint=25
```